# How to pass onChange Event to Child Input Component in React ts

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

[Input Component Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9BuY.png)             -
[Form Component Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UzrK.png)

I have added Image of both components above

I want to use input component in my form component but onChange event is not tracking the input correctly and input does not show any value after typing anything please help

Comment: Use React Context

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: If you add a console.log(name, value) in you handleInputChange, does that trigger every time you change your input, and does it console log what you'd expect? My suspicion is that the InputField doesn't know it needs to re-render

Comment: Further to what I've said, if you add key to your InputField, that might help
`key={formData.name}`. That means every time the name changes, it knows to re-render the component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.